# Hungarian assignment alternative with large and unbalanced profit matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, knapsack-problem, hungarian-algorithm

I need help with solving assignment problem in particular cases. In one scenario the profit matrix dimension 2000 by 23000 (2000 items and 23000 bins, where each bin can only contain one item, and there's no negative profit). If Hungarian assignment is applied, the algorithm will firstly create a square matrix of 23000 by 23000, and caused OutOfMemory exception.

The problem I want to solve is just what the maximum profit that the optimal assignment scheme can produce. Hence there is no need to output the actual optimal assignment, **just the optimal value** is needed. Also this value can just be an **approximation**. I wonder if there exists an alternative way which can save memory and computation cost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually simulate all of the dummy columns with just one column.

I don't know what specific instructions you're following, but one of the steps in the algorithm is to cover every zero in the matrix using the fewest number of horizontal and vertical lines possible. At the start when all of the dummy columns are still zero, the most efficient way to cover them would be to cover them column-wise. Some rows may be covered as well, and the values that are covered twice are incremented by an amount. More importantly, *the same row in every dummy column will be incremented by the same amount*.

Continuing on now that some of the rows of the dummy columns are not zero, we reach this step again. Since all of the dummy columns are still identical, it follows that if it is efficient for one dummy column to be covered, they will all be covered. So even though the values may change, *every dummy column will always be identical to every other dummy column*, so you can represent them all using only one array.

You may still run into problems if you have a lot of real data, but this should help in situations like the one you mentioned.